# DelegateCommand in Listview with UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, user-controls, windows-store-apps

How can I use DelegateCommand in my Lisview with Usercontrol? In my Listview i'm using it like that:

```
<ListView x:Name="peopleListBox">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                            <UserControls:ItemTemplateControl QuestionText="{Binding parametr}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView>
```

I'm trying that in the UserControl:

```
 <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenCommand, ElementName=peopleListBox}"/>
```

and this:

```
 <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding Path=OpenCommand, ElementName=peopleListBox}"/>
```

Neither of this codes works.

UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App13.UserControls.ItemTemplateControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local1="using:App13"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click" Foreground="Black" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenCommand, ElementName=peopleListBox}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Why would you use a button with the same command in a `DataTemplate`? The template is for all the items. Do you want the same button with the same command over and over again?

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `UserControl`?

Comment: It's just a sample that show how can i use button with command in listview(not in usercontrol)

Comment: @meilke, This is my code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `peopleListBox` inside your user control's XAML. It is a field defined in the parent control and inaccessible in the child control.

The code you provided works for me (the list view template button click calls the command handler):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="peopleListBox">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Command="{Binding 
                                           DataContext.OpenCommand, 
                                           ElementName=peopleListBox}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The view model I used:

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        OpenCommand = new RelayCommand(o => {  });
    }

    public RelayCommand OpenCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the main window contructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = new VM();
  peopleListBox.Items.Add(new object());
}
```

And obviously you cannot use `peopleListBox` inside the user control. It is a field defined in the parent control and inaccessible in the child control.

Comment: My code works fine when i put my button in Listview. I can't use binding in my `UserControl` with button

Comment: Check the bottom part of my answer.